# Расписание на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, с чего начать.
Хочу сделать что-то наподобие расписания - месяц в виде сетки дней, которые в зависимости от занятости закрашиваются нужным цветом. Выходной - зеленый, рабочий день - красный.
Желательно, чтобы отображался как-то именно текущий месяц.
Даже не знаю, с чего начать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уважаемый [[@Batyabest](/users/22866/batyabest)](/users/22866/batyabest), прежде чем что-то говорить конкретное по вашему заданию, хотел сказать, что тут, помимо php, еще надо и верстать (знать html, css, если вы хотите нарисовать красивое расписание-календарь), планировать задачи (а значит что-то хранить в базе данных. Например, работать с mysql), а вы, похоже, это плохо понимаете. Формулировать вопросы надо, когда конкретно что-то в коде не получается, а не когда у вас элементарно нет идей даже в голове.

Насчет календаря вот несколько ссылок, какие реализуют календари:

- [Ссылка первая](http://sitear.ru/material/php-kalendar-skript-kalendarya-dlya-sayta-na-php)
- [Ссылка вторая](http://janicky.com/stati/sozdanie-php-kalendarya)
- [Ссылка третья](http://www.softtime.ru/scripts/calendar.php)

Юзайте ссылки и пользуйтесь самостоятельно поисковиком для решения своих проблем. Допилить вышеизложенные коды календарей не представляется трудным, на мой взгляд, с учетом того, что я прочитал о вашем пожелании в вопросе. Удачи в работе!

Comment: Конкретнее тогда напишу, есть некая таблица с заявками, в которой для календаря важно в принципе только поле дата. Соответственно, нужно вывести так: если у пользователя с ID=N на дату например, 31-09-2014 есть заявка (то есть есть информация в БД), то она должна закраситься например красным цветом (то есть занять пользователь), ну и иначе соответственно зеленым (свободен).
Вот помогите мне запрос к базе сформулировать.